# What is the appropriate way to load a list from backend dynamically using useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm running into useEffect loop problems as a beginner.

I want to display a list of users from the backend dynamically on the myOrders page.
I have a Redux action called getMyOrders() that grab the list from the API and add it to the myOrders reducer state.

Requirements:

1. Show most recent list
2. If list is modified in any way on this page or a different page, it should refresh and show the updated list.

I have this useEffect code that's problematic...

```
export const myOrdersListReducer = (state = { myOrders:[] }, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'MY_ORDERS_REQUEST':
            return { loading: true }
        case 'MY_ORDERS_SUCCESS':
            return { loading: false, myOrders: action.payload }
        case 'MY_ORDERS_ERROR':
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        case 'MY_ORDERS_RESET':
            return { myOrders:[]}
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

```
// MyOrders State
const { myOrders } = useSelector(state => state.myOrdersList)

useEffect(()=> {
    if (!myOrders < 1)
    dispatch(getmyOrders())
}, [myOrders])
```

The problem with this code is if myOrders has no orders, it will loop.

I also found this same problem in the way I'm thinking if myOrders is an object.

The condition is about myOrders, I'm dispatching to update myOrders and I'm also monitoring myOrders which causes the useEffect to run every time the state changes.

It seems like such a simple request to get the latest list/object on page load, and then show it if it changes, but monitoring the list in the dependency and dispatching to update the state merely loops.

Any tips from more experienced devs?

Comment: Your condition is to `getMyOrders` anytime `myOrders` changes. Problem is, myOrders before and myOrders after getMyOrders is fired are not the same array, even if they're both an empty array, so they're not equivalent. That's why you're getting a loop.

Comment: To check for an update on myOrders, do a comparison with a local myOrders variable (useState) and fire your dispatch when they're different. If some other component updates myOrders useEffect will fire.

Comment: This all assuming I'm filling in the blanks appropriately.

Comment: Thanks yeah i think i see the problem but I’m still not clear on how to fix it. So myOrders is not updated until the dispatch is called. So i think monitoring myOrders might have been incorrect. I need to check if the backend matches myOrders actually. I can add an order from the checkout page and update backend but myOrders wont see this until dispatch is called. 

So maybe i need to dispatch on a general condition like if an user is logged in. And if i delete an order it should dispatch again and i leave myorders out of the dependency/useEffect entirely?

Comment: That's kind of what I expected was happening. You could write a custom hook to handle checking the backend; I would trigger it on login, and whenever you're interacting with the orders (write, update, and delete). What it should do is compare the list (array) of orders coming from the DB to the myOrders array in your store. To do that I create a simple helper function that sorts each array by order id and then JSON.stringify, then do a `===` comparison. If it's different, replace the store myOrders with the fetched orders. Now you can remove `if (!myOrders < 1)` and it should fire when needed.

Comment: Thanks that should also work! I’ll give the a shot